# Better way to insert intervals between other intervals?

Tags: javascript, arrays

From the backend I'm receiving an array like this:

```
[
  {index: 0, start: '07:00', end: '09:00'},
  {index: 1, start: '09:00', end: '11:00'},
  {index: 0, start: '12:00', end: '15:00'},
]
```

In order to better work with it I decided to try and convert it into something like this:

```
// this is array1
[
  {index: 0, time: startInMilliseconds},
  {index: 1, time: startInMilliseconds}, // no difference between 0's end and 1's start, no no null here
  {index: null, time: endInMilliseconds},
  {index: 0, time: startInMilliseconds},
  {index: null, time: endInMilliseconds}
]
```

because I need to be able to insert and replace intervals like so: if I insert an object with `start: '08:00'` and `end: '08:30'` it should split the first interval in two. If `start: '10:00'` and `end: '12:30'`, the the previous interval should end at 10:00, the next should start at 12:30 and the blank period between them should disappear.

Currently I'm trying to do it with a for loop and many `if`'s after sorting the objects by time, like this:

```
intervals.push(
    {index: index, time: startInMilliseconds, new: true},
    {index: null, time: endInMilliseconds, new: true}
);

intervals.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.time < b.time) return -1;
    if(a.time > b.time) return 1;
    if(!a.new && b.new) return -1;
    if(a.new && !b.new) return 1;
    return 0;
});

for(let i=0, iStart=null, lastIndex=null; i<intervals.length; i++){
    if(intervals[i].time == startInMilliseconds){
        if(intervals[i].new){
            if(intervals[i-1] && intervals[i-1].index == intervals[i].index){
                iStart = i-1;
                intervals.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }else{
                iStart = i;
                delete intervals[i].new;
            }
        }else{
            intervals.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
        continue;
    }
    if(iStart != null && intervals[i].time <= endInMilliseconds && !intervals[i].new){
        lastIndex = intervals[i].index;
        intervals.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    if(iStart != null && intervals[i].time == endInMilliseconds && intervals[i].new){
        if(lastIndex == intervals[iStart].index) intervals.splice(i, 1);
        else{
            intervals[i].index = lastIndex;
            delete intervals[i].new;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This is obviously hard to follow and doesn't fully work, but I can't think of another way. I don't know how to properly describe it to Google either.

Here are some examples for clarification of what array1 should look like after performing some actions. Assume the strings are times in milliseconds:

```
// insert {index: 2, start: '08:00', end: '08:30'}

[
  {index: 0, time: '07:00'},
  {index: 2, time: '08:00'},
  {index: 0, time: '08:30'},
  {index: 1, time: '09:00'},
  {index: null, time: '11:00'},
  {index: 0, time: '12:00'},
  {index: null, time: '15:00'}
]

// insert {index: 2, start: '10:00', end: '12:30'}

[
  {index: 0, time: '07:00'},
  {index: 1, time: '09:00'},
  {index: 2, time: '10:00'},
  {index: 0, time: '12:30'},
  {index: null, time: '15:00'}
]

// insert {index: 1, start: '10:00', end: '12:30'}

[
  {index: 0, time: '07:00'},
  {index: 1, time: '09:00'},
  {index: 0, time: '12:30'},
  {index: null, time: '15:00'}
]
```

Comment: please add the part before splitting and after splitting in two parts, data wise.

Comment: Converting to a common factor is a good start, but I suggest minutes as that's the smallest interval you need and the numbers are much simpler to work with (1,440 per day vs 86,400,000). You need to explain the logic more, e.g. does a new interval from 9:00 to 10:00 replace/delete an interval from 9:30 to 9:45?

Comment: @NinaScholz I added examples at the end, hope that's what you meant.

Comment: great. please add the original array with `null` values, too. what is the meaning of `null` here?

Comment: @RobG I use functions to convert them so if I want to manually insert a value I do it like `getTimeInMs('07:00');`. The function makes a new date object for jan 1st 1970 and returns the total milliseconds since 00:00, I don't work with the ms directly other than comparing if they are equal.

Comment: @NinaScholz The second array is the original with null. null means empty space, the space between the second and third intervals, and after the end of the third interval.

Comment: @Nadroev—yes, by all means convert to a common factor, but using a Date to generate milliseconds is less than optimal, e.g. `let [h, m] = time.split(':'); return h*60 + m*1` where *time* is a string like "07:30". You can change the factors to get ms if you like, but minutes have smaller values that are easier to convert mentally to h:mm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to refactor your code, the following uses the raw array format and sequential processing of the intervals. Hopefully the comments are sufficient.

I reduce the time to minutes, you can use any common factor you like, just replace the *timeToMins* function with whatever suits. It also removes an interval that is reduced to zero time, i.e. start and end are the same. It assumes the intervals are sorted and valid, i.e. values, start < end, ranges don't overlap, (but inserted interval can overlap an existing one) etc.

When splitting a range it uses Object.assign to copy the current interval, which works for simple objects but you'll need something better if the objects are more complex.

```js
// Convert time in HH:mm to minutes
function timeToMins(time) {
  let [h, m] = time.split(':');
  return h*60 + m*1;
}

function insertInterval(arr, nInterval) {
  var nStart = timeToMins(nInterval.start);
  var nEnd   = timeToMins(nInterval.end);
  var inserted = false;
  var temp;
  
  // Insert after current if after true, otherwise before
  function insert(after) {
    if (!inserted) {
      arr.splice(i + Number(!!after), 0, nInterval);
      inserted = true;
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     let cInterval = arr[i];
     let cStart = timeToMins(cInterval.start);
     let cEnd   = timeToMins(cInterval.end);
     
    // Cases where new start <= current start
    if (nStart <= cStart) {
      // If before first or between another range
      if (nEnd <= cStart) {
        insert();
        return;
      // If overlaps start only
      } else if (nEnd <= cEnd) {
        insert();
        cInterval.start = nInterval.end;
      // If overlaps end too, remove current
      } else if (nEnd >= cEnd) {
        insert();
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        --i;
      }
    // cases where new start > current start
    } else {  // if (nStart > cStart) {
      // If starts in the range
      if (nStart < cEnd) {
        insert(true);
        temp = cInterval.end; // Remember end in case it's needed below
        cInterval.end = nInterval.start;
      }
      // If also ends in the range, need to split range
      if (nEnd < cEnd) {
        insert(true);
        var tail = Object.assign({}, cInterval);
        tail.start = nInterval.end;
        tail.end = temp;
        arr.splice(++i, 0, tail);
      }
    }
    // If cInterval is now of zero length, remove it
    if (cInterval.start == cInterval.end) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      --i;
    }
  }
  // If didn't get inserted, must be after last
  if (!inserted) arr.push(nInterval);
}

// Examples
var data = [
  {index: 0, start: '07:00', end: '08:00'}, // 0
  {index: 1, start: '09:00', end: '10:00'}, // 1
  {index: 0, start: '10:00', end: '11:00'}  // 2
];

// Some interesting cases, there are many more to test...
[ {index: 1, start: '07:05', end:'07:15'},  // Splits first
  {index: 1, start: '08:05', end:'08:15'},  // Between 0 & 1  
  {index: 0, start: '09:30', end: '10:15'}  // Overlaps 1 end & 2 start
].forEach( interval => {
  insertInterval(data, interval);
  console.log(data.map(a=>JSON.stringify(a)).join('\n'));
});
```